# iOS 7: Two different heights for cells in a table inheriting from the same UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I need "Two different heights for cells in a table inheriting from the same UITableViewCell".

A bit more on this. I am using iOS 7 and storyboard. I created on the story board two different UITableViewCell prototype for a UITableView with custom cells.

I then created a class, MyUITableViewCell which defines the beheaviour of the cell as well as a protocol method that is then implemented by the delegate (which is in my case is the UITableViewController class where the UITableView containing the cells is).

Now.. I would like to dynamically set the row of the cells according to whether the cells is of type 1 or type 2.

I have found this method:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // if(indexPath) refers to cell of type 1 then
    // return 240;

    // else return 120;

    // I created a NSDictionary with data that includes the type of cell information, however I am not sure how to link indexPath to the dictionary. The keys of the dictionary are ids and not array indexes.. so I am a bit lost in here..
}
```

As said in the comment:

"I created a NSDictionary with data that includes the type of cell information, however I am not sure how to link indexPath to the dictionary. The keys of the dictionary are ids and not array indexes.. so I am a bit lost in here.."

I would like to find a solution to this but not sure if it is possible using only NSDictionary or if I need some other hack...

Comment: What logic are you using in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to determine which cell to use based on the `indexPath`? Use the same login in `heightForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: I think you know the indexPath's right ? check in heightForRowAtIndexPath method  and set height of the cell

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do that. The cells in your table view are data backed, you must have access to the data that defines the table in the table view delegate.

If your table is simple with only one section then you might only need to look at `indexPath.row`. There must be some way to relate this value to your data, if there is not you will not be able to populate the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` either.

Often the `indexPath.row` value can be used as an index into an array containing data, such as `[tableDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` In your case, if the data is a dictionary, what are the keys? Maybe you can make a key directly from the row (`[NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.row]`, since a key must be an object) or maybe you need to use an array to translate the `NSNumber` produced from the index paths into the keys that are used in your dictionary. If your data is pre-existing and it would be a lot of work to change it this might be the best way, otherwise think about organising your data for easy access.

An alternative would be to use a `UICollectionView`, where with a custom `UICollectionViewLayout` you can define the frame of every cell individually at the time you report attributes for the cell. However you still need a way to relate index path to the underlying data. It is more versatile than a `UITableView` and is possibly a more useful skill to develop with the state of iOS development today.